# How to create a velodrome shape?

Tags: android

An ellipse is easy to create. So is a rectangle with rounded corners. But how do I create a velodrome shape?

That is, half a circle to the left + rectangle in the middle + half circle to the right. Like a straight sausage, if you want.

I want this as an `XML` drawable to be used as background for a `TextView`.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing **is** a rectangle with rounded corners, just a specific class of one. Simply increase the radius of your corners to half the height of your rectangle.

Comment: Can you specify half the height in XML?

Comment: I see. Yeah, it might be difficult to do it in XML with this approach. You could also try two circles with a rectangle in the middle. I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect you might be able to do something with scale drawables and/or clip drawables. I'd have to think about it some more.